# Change root view controller dynamically from storyboard?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have an app which uses a navigation controller to record measurement data for the user. The first screen is reused multiple times depending on the user settings. They can choose to measure say their arms, legs, stomach, etc, there is over ten choices. The second screen records weight and the third screen shows a summary.

Logic in screen A determines which segue to call for whether to go to screen B or C or back to screen A.

But...

If the user only selects to record their weight, is it possible to skip screen A altogether? Note that I don't want it to appear on the stack at all, ie no back button from screen B to screen A if it is skipped.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: In viewDidLoad method you can write     self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sending me in the right direction @rajath, I was over complicating it! Your code didn't work though

```
 [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Did hide the button, but when I popped to the root it caused funny behaviour. However, using the same principle I did this which worked a treat:

```
 NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```